# How can I instantiate an object from a given class within a method from another class?

Tags: python

From the below example, I understand that I can instantiate an object of class A within a method of class B while neither of which are related to each other (B is no child/parent of A).

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,Aa,Ab):
        self.Aa = Aa
        self.Ab = Ab
    def method_from_A(self,target):
        return self.Aa + self.Ab + target

class B:
    def __init__(self,Ba,Bb):
        self.Ba = Ba
        self.Bb = Bb
    def method_from_B(self,target):
        objA = A(1,2)
        num  = objA.method_from_A(3) + target
        print("How can I did this?")
        return num
```

```
objB = B(1,3)
objB.method_from_B(3)
```

What is allowing this behavior to occur? What is going on under the hood?

How can I access something inside class B that had not been passed as an input argument?
Is there no danger in allowing such behaviors?

btw: I need this behavior, but I would prefer to explicitly pass the class A as an input argument to mehotd_from_B. Is this even possible?

Comment: When `method_from_B` gets called on an instance of `B`, Python simply starts climbing up the stack to each parent frame looking for where `A` might be defined.

Comment: It is *very* common to instantiate an instance of another class inside a method. You do it every time you create a string or number in a method. Also, there's nothing stopping you from passing a class or instance as an argument — that's also very common.

Comment: Note that this is considered an anti-pattern -- I recommend reading about dependency inversion. Ideally, you'd pass an instance of `A` either to the constructor of `B`, or as a argument to `method_from_B`. Classes should generally not instantiate other custom classes inside them.

Comment: @ddejohn Let's suppose I need to use the method_from_A more than once with different input arguments inside method_from_B. I guess I would need to pass the class A instead of a fixed instantiated object. Is this seen as something you should not do? I mean: is passing a class, instead of an instance, more dangerous?

Comment: Are you talking about using static methods? Are the methods from A you want to call static methods? It's not super clear what you're trying to do. What do the arguments to `objA.some_method()` have to do with how `objA` was instantiated?

Comment: @ddejohn you are right. I may have made it more complicated. What I meant was, what if I need to instantiate more than one (maybe 10 or 20, depending on the case) object of class A inside method_from_b? I guess I would have to pass in the class, not the instances. Is there any harm in doing so? I am getting the idea that is Ok to pass instances but is not OK classes as input arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to pass it as an argument:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,Aa,Ab):
        self.Aa = Aa
        self.Ab = Ab
    def method_from_A(self,target):
        return self.Aa + self.Ab + target

class B:
    def __init__(self,Ba,Bb):
        self.Ba = Ba
        self.Bb = Bb
    def method_from_B(self,target, a):
        num  = a(1, 2).method_from_A(3) + target
        print("How can I did this?")
        return num
```

```
objB = B(1,3)
objB.method_from_B(3, A)
```

Output

```
How can I did this?
9
```

Comment: @Mark Is there any drawback of passing the class instead of an instance? What if I need to do something like what Nin17 is proposing: Passing the class to be used in a more general way inside method_from_B?